# ElasticSearch: Returning products based on name and categories

Tags: php, elasticsearch

im having troubles returning all the product that match a specific condition:

My mapping is quite simple

i have products, they have names, and they'are in certain categories.

What i want to do is return all the product that either have a string that i choose in their name, aswell has returning all the product that also are in the category for the same string.

Here's an example:

say i type 'Mobile phone', i should get all the products that have 'Mobile Phone' somewhere in the string 'name' (order and such doesn't matter) but it should also return all the product in the 'Mobile Phone' category (whatever the name is)

At the moment, i have a query that gets a lot of garbage because it matchs any of the words in the name, and doesn't get all of the categories.

```
BoolQuery {#612 ▼
  #_params: array:2 [▼
    "must" => array:3 [▼
      0 => ProductAvailable {#613 ▶}
      1 => Term {#622 ▶}
      2 => BoolQuery {#623 ▼
        #_params: array:3 [▼
          "minimum_number_should_match" => 1
          "should" => array:2 [▼
            0 => Match {#624 ▼
              #_params: array:1 [▼
                "name" => "Tondeuse à gazon"
              ]
              #_rawParams: []
            }
            1 => Match {#625 ▼
              #_params: array:1 [▼
                "category.name.raw" => "Tondeuse à gazon"
              ]
              #_rawParams: []
            }
          ]
          "boost" => 2
        ]
        #_rawParams: []
      }
    ]
    "minimum_number_should_match" => 1
  ]
  #_rawParams: []
}
```

The ProductAvailable and Term query aren't relevant since they're used to check if product can be selled etc...

Here the example string is "Tondeuse à gazon"

Thanks for the helping <3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution myself i'll mark the question answered

Comment: this is sick you don't share it

Comment: code is lost at this point sorry, i would if i still had it... im not working it that company anymore, but i can share some info if you have questions